# strange behavioiur by dynamically setting methods

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic

I found out a "strange" behavior of when adding methods dynamically to a class. When I do it one by one (non iteratively) everything works fine [*Sample 1*] but when I try to loop the task then it seems the all the methods points to the body of the last added method [*Sample 2.A*]. In a further attempt [*Sample 2.B*] I end up again to the same "strange" result.

Could you help me find out what is the origin of such behavior and how to fix it?

I am using `python 3.9.6`

Here the code samples:

**Test functions**

```
def a(): print('a()')
def a1(): print('a1()')
def a2(p='p'): print('a2({})'.format(p))
```

**Sample 1:** one by one approach (correct behavior)

```
class Test1(object): pass

setattr(Test1, a.__name__, lambda self, *args, **kwargs: a(*args, **kwargs))
setattr(Test1, a1.__name__, lambda self, *args, **kwargs: a1(*args, **kwargs))
setattr(Test1, a2.__name__, lambda self, *args, **kwargs: a2(*args, **kwargs))

Test1().a()
Test1().a1()
Test1().a2()
```

Output

```
a()
a1()
a2(p)
```

**Sample 2.A:** "strange" behavior - iterative approach

```
class Test2(object): pass

for f in [a, a1, a2]:

    setattr(Test2, f.__name__, lambda self, *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs))
    # print(f.__name__, hasattr(Test2, f.__name__))   # debug: correct output
    # eval("Test2().{}()".format(f.__name__))   #       debug: correct output


Test2().a()
Test2().a1()
Test2().a2()
print(dir(Test2))    # the methods have right signature but same body!
```

Output

```
a2(p)
a2(p)
a2(p)
[..., 'a', 'a1', 'a2']
```

**Sample 2.B:** "strange" behavior - factory approach

```
Test3 = type('Test3', (object,), {f.__name__: lambda self, *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs) for f in [a, a1, a2]})


Test3().a()
Test3().a1()
Test3().a2()
print(dir(Test3))    # the methods have right signature but same body!
```

Output

```
a2(p)
a2(p)
a2(p)
[..., 'a', 'a1', 'a2']
```

Comment: have you looked at `print(dir(Test2())) `?

Comment: Return the same result: ```print(dir(Test2()) == dir(Test2))``` return ```True```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

using an auxiliary function for the function-method binding is enough to avoid scoping problem.

```
class TestClass:
    pass


def func2method(func):
    # auxiliary function: needed to avoid for-loop scope problems
    return lambda self, *args, **kwargs: func(*args, **kwargs) # <- the extra parameter is needed for the binding with the class

# binding step
for f in (a, a1, a2):
    setattr(TestClass, f.__name__, func2method(f))


t = TestClass()
t.a()        # a()
t.a1()       # a1()
t.a2()       # a2(p)
t.a()        # a()
print(t.a)   # <bound method func2method.<locals>.<lambda> of <__main__.TestClass object at 0x7ff4df787a30>>
```

---

Thanks to the considerations of Chris Doyle I come out with the solution of the problems (at least the syntactical side).

*Solution of Sample 2.A:* "strange" behavior - iterative approach

```
class Test2(object): pass

for f in [a, a1, a2]:
   setattr(Test2, f.__name__, \
            eval('lambda self,*args, **kwargs: {}(*args, **kwargs)'.format(f.__name__))) # ok

Test2().a()
Test2().a1()
Test2().a2()
```

Output

```
a()
a1()
a2(p)
```

*Remarks*

1. it is important that `eval` acts on the full `lambda` expression, if it were only the return value, `eval("f(*args, **kwargs)"`,  then same problem as before
2. for an `eval`-free solution, pass the the iteration variable, `f`, as a key-value parameter of the anonymous function
   `setattr(Test2, f.__name__, lambda self, f=f, *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs))`

*Solution of Sample 2.B:* "strange" behavior - factory approach

```
d = {f.__name__: eval('lambda self, *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs)', dict(f=f, )) for f in [a, a1, a2]}  # ok

Test3 = type('Test3', (object,), d)

Test3().a()
Test3().a1()
Test3().a2()
```

*Output*

```
a()
a1()
a2(p)
```

*Remarks*

for an `eval`-free solution it holds the same argumentation as above with

`d = {f.__name__: lambda self, f=f, *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs) for f in [a, a1, a2]}`

I guess the origin of the problem is some kind of conflict with the nested scopes. If someone want to add some remarks on this point then the question can be considered solved.

I am also open to different solution of course... maybe using `nonlocal` keyword or even more exotic suffs:)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a more simplified example to try to explain what is happening here.

```py
funcs = []

for i in range(5):
    print(i + 1)
    funcs.append(lambda: i + 1)

print("exec lambdas")   
for func in funcs:
    print(func())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1
2
3
4
5
exec lambdas
5
5
5
5
5
```

Now this shows the same behaviour as your issues. At the time of setting the lambda we see the value of i is increasing. However when i later call the lambdas they all return same value.

The issue here is I am telling the lambda, when i call you I want you to return the value of `i + 1`. However by the time i come to execte the lambdas function, the loop has finished. And the value of `i` after the loop is now 4. Since all the lambdas say the same thing, return the value of `i + 1` and the value of `i` is now 4, all executions of the lambda return the same value, since they all refer to `i` and at the end of the loop `i` is set to 4.

The same thing is happening in your case. You are setting the attribute `f.__name__` which is evaluated during the loop. Then creating a lambda that when executed later will then evaluate f. By the time you execute the lambda its after the loop so at that point `f` will be pointing to `a2` So all your attributes `a` `a1` `a2` will all call and evaluate `f` after the loop meaning f is pointing to the last item it was set to which is `a2`

Comment: Ok, good remark, so you reconduce the problem to an other (and an simpler one!). I fixed the new problem in "2.5" different ways: 1st ```for i in range(5): funcs.append(lambda i=i: i + 1) ```, 2nd way ```f = eval('lambda : {} + 1'.format(i))``` and 2.5 way ```exec('f = lambda : {} + 1'.format(i))```. These solve your problem but I still have difficult to apply these patterns to the original problem. Can you help me out? So the reason of the "strange" behavior is about variable scope and run-time scope?